# Identifying charger for each mac

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

As we are many people living together and each at his/her MacBook some M1 and some old, the chargers get mixed a lot.

Is there a way to identify from number/printed text on the charger which model it belongs to?

Comment: You can use low tech : add a sticker with power delivery and/or MacBook model and/or username. Also add one around the cord if it can be detached from power adapter.

Answer (score 4):

[This guide at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) breaks things down superbly. There is a myriad of power adapters, connectors and laptops not easily paraphrased in a short answer here.

Once you've figured out whose power adapter is whose, get a Sharpie or a P-Touch label machine and mark them up!

Comment: I know it is frowned upon at AskDifferent to give single-link answers, but the information on the Support page is not easily openly plagiarized, (with suitable editing and thorough attribution,) because of the complexity involved in translating a page rich with visual information into purely textual form. I cannot say with certainty that the Support page above will be available from Apple in perpetuity, but seeing that 1/ Apple is pretty consistent with it's documentation and 2/ Apple's not going anywhere anytime soon, this information is timeless and will always be available in some form.

Comment: Sure but then you could also have provided that link and its description as a comment to the OP which I think would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Alper - fair enough. I did consider adding it as a comment, but after an inordinate amount of research, I could find _no better or more comprehensive source_ of the definitive information needed by folks in the OP's position now, and for others in the future. Chances are Apple is in a far better position to keep this information current than some random reddit posts or tech website articles. To me, at least, Apple's page _is_ the answer. If a moderator agrees with you, I'm willing to strike it as an answer and make it a brief comment.